# Url Loader, loading my background image once then after refreshing the page it fails to appear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I'm using next.js with file-loader and url-loader to load in images into my React components like below:

```
import background from '@/assets/mountain-shot.jpg';
const Section = styled.section`
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  background-image: url(${background});
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

  box-shadow: inset 2px 33px 97px -21px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  position: relative;
`;
```

As you can see I'm importing an image and outputting it in the styled components. If I remove the background image it loads with the background #f3f3f3 and then I put back in the background image the image does load. It is at this point that I do a refresh that the image and all other styling in this block disappears.

I figured this might be an issue with my next.config setup so I will paste this below here:

```
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|gif|png|jp(e*)g)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
        name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

We are using Next.js to do our SSR this might be worth mentioning.

When I console log background I get this value on the first load where it works: 
`/_next/webpack/images/b3f1c5846e75c47d10b0fa02957ac1b4-mountain-shot.jpg`

And on the second load where it the styling disappears I get exactly the same url but it does not appear.

** update **

I've noticed now that when the image appears on the first time you can make changes and it will still be viewable. It isn't actaully until you do a hard/soft refresh that is disappears.

Answer (score 2):

The url has to be a string inside a string:

```
 url("${background}");
```

Comment: thanks but it can be just a path inside a url. Anyway this doesn't fix my issue I'm afraid I've tried this.

Comment: Any other ideas by any chance?

Comment: @max that should fix `all other styling in this block disappears.`

Comment: Afraid this isn't the case. If I add the quotes it does fix this issue but when I then refresh the page that component doesn't have any styling again. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @max have you tried logging what `background` actually is?

Comment: Basically outputs the right url but it is like it doesn't exists yet :S